# @astrojs/image does not work properly when I use images with external links

Tags: astrojs

I use @astrojs/image
But when I use the address of a photo with an external link, it does not show the photo in the production environment

`<Picture src={imageInfo?.imageUrl} widths={[200, 400, 800]}  aspectRatio={16/9} sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px"  alt={imageInfo?.alternativeText} />`

Answer (score 0):

[Remote images](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/#remote-images) have a few required props (`src`, `alt`, `format`, and dimensions). It looks like your missing a [`format`](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/image/#format)

Comment: I used it in this way, it shows the photo in the dev environment, but it does not show in the production environment